# How To Get Data From Api And Display It To Related Control In Dynamic Table When User Select An Item From Select2 In Laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-select2-4

How To Get Data From Api And Display It To Related Control In Dynamic Table When User Select An Item From Select2 In Laravel?

I am using Laravel with select2. In my form I am adding select2 and input-text dynamically and getting select2 data from server using ajax request and its working fine.
Here I am using select2 for 'Ledger' and input-text for 'Balance' in dynamic table. Their have a 'Add' button to add new row in table. I want to call an Api to get Ledger
balance and display it on balance input-text when user select an item from select2 accordingly.

I am using below code when select2 initialize and it is working fine for newly created row.

```
 $('.select2_el').on('select2:select', function (e) {               
                var query= $(this).val();
                console.log(query);    
            });
```

But when i change the item of pre selected item from select2 it is fire multiple times. Ex. if i have three rows and If i will change first select2 controls item then
in console it showing same value but three times. How can i prevent this?

As we know this is a dynamic table with control, How can i display Ledger balance accordingly to their balance input-text?

Take a look in [jsfiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/chandanacharjee/8jm073vq)

Comment: Hey Chandan,
Whatever you will select in the Ledger dropdown, their value will be get from the API and their value set in the balance input-text, correct?

Comment: Yes. Mitesh Rathod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering your query, considering you are using table tags.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.select2_el', function(event) {
    let selected_value = $(this).val()
    // it get goes to your <tr> tag
    let tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    
    // it will find inside your balance input-box and set the value.
    tr.find('input[name="balance[]"]').val(selected_value);
});
```

Hope this will save your time!!

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working fine. Mitesh Rathod

Comment: Mate, feel free give a up vote! I will be thankful.